# replace object by another object

Tags: angular, typescript

i have an organization object that contains and address object, i want to edit the address object with the values that i get from the form, then i want to change the address object that is in the organisation object with the new object address, so i used `Object.assign`, but it always returns the old address

```
export class Organization {
    public address?: Address;
    public telecoms?: Telecom[];
    public metier?: Dictionary;
}

export class Address {
    public zipCode?: Dictionary;
    public country?: Dictionary;
    public city?: string;
}

export class Dictionary {
    public id?: number;
    public code?: string;
    public label?: string;
}

this.organizationService.getOneById(this.id).subscribe((organization: Organization) => this.organization= organization });

const address = this.editForm.get("address").value;

console.log(JSON.stringify({ address })); // {"address":{"country":{"id":2},"zipCode":{"id":1}}} 

let organiationToSave: Organization = this.organization;

Object.assign({}, organiationToSave , JSON.stringify({ address }));

console.log(organiationToSave);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Object.assign({}, organiationToSave , JSON.stringify({ address }));

console.log(organiationToSave);
```

In the above code, you are assigning values to a new object `{}`, then you log `organiationToSave`. This makes no sense.

Maybe you want to do this instead?

```
const obj = Object.assign({}, organiationToSave , JSON.stringify({ address }));

console.log(obj);
```

Or if you want to update `organiationToSave`, do this:

```
Object.assign(organiationToSave , JSON.stringify({ address }));

console.log(organiationToSave);
```

Comment: i want to update `organiationToSave`, so i used `Object.assign(organiationToSave , JSON.stringify({ address }));` but i show me this erreur `Cannot add property 0, object is not extensible `

Comment: @AymenKanzari This is because some part of your code (which is not shown in your question) uses `Object.preventExtensions()`. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cant_define_property_object_not_extensible). This is another problem for another question, though.

Comment: i'm not used `Object.preventExtensions()` in any part of my code, i get the `organization` from the `organizationService.getOneById`, then i want to update this organization.

Comment: @AymenKanzari That is a separate problem, you should ask it in a separate question, and we will try to help you there. Regarding this one, consider upvoting and selecting the best answer.

P.S. I bet `getOneById` contains the `Object.preventExtensions()` code.